# Ways to fetched the credentials of the logged in user in Salesforce SDK iOS

Tags: salesforce1-app, ios

Is there a way to get the details/credentials (email, password, name, etc.) of the logged in user using salesforce SDK or even third party libraries?. After allot of googling and searching, i found this link but doesn't work on me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447328/query-for-username-in-salesforce-ios-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the current user ID from the `userId` property on `SFOAuthCredentials` after authentication succeeds. Then you can just issue a SOQL query for the `User` object to fetch any fields you like, including email, name, profile, etc. You certainly cannot fetch the user's password in that way, nor should you be able to -- that's the entire point of OAuth.

Comment: In fact, OAuth is specifically designed to exposing exposing passwords outside the authentication system.

Comment: Is there a way to do this by querying the API without issuing a network call?

Comment: Sorry, what? If you're talking to a remote API, you are necessarily making a network call.